# Less module build failed in webpack after migrating from grunt

Tags: css, webpack, less

I can't figure out how to compile my less files to css and then include them in my build folder, without the app failing to run. Trying to build/run the application returns the following error:

```
ERROR in ./content/styles/less/ts.less
Module build failed: 

@import "node_modules/bootstrap/less/mixins/buttons.less";
@import "node_modules/Font-awesome/less/font-awesome.less";
^
Can't resolve './node_modules/Font-awesome/less/font-awesome.less' in '/home/thinkpad/work/EPD.SPA/EpdSPA/content/styles/less'
      in /home/thinkpad/work/EPD.SPA/EpdSPA/content/styles/less/ts.less (line 4, column 0)
 @ multi ./content/styles/less/for.less ./content/styles/less/kladd.less ./content/styles/less/ts.less
```

To clarify: These files have already proved to be working with grunt. The webpack migration triggered these errors.
I'm using the webpack config examples from [here](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin). My config file:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var globby = require('globby');
var path = require('path');

var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
var AssetsPlugin = require('assets-webpack-plugin');
var CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

const extractLESS = new ExtractTextPlugin('stylesheets/[name]-two.css');
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: globby.sync(['./app/app.js','./app/app.run.js', './app/app.config.js', './app/**/*.js']),
        styles: globby.sync(['./content/styles/*.css']),
        lessStyles: globby.sync(['./content/styles/less/*.less']), 
        images: globby.sync(['./content/images/**/*.*']),
        vendor: [
            // removed to save space
        ]
    },
    output: {
        filename: './scripts/[name].bundle.js',
        path: path.join(__dirname, "public")
    },
    devServer: {
        port: 1384,
        contentBase: './public/'
    },

    // Enable sourcemaps for debugging webpack's output.
    devtool: 'source-map',

    module: {
        rules: [
            {    test: /\.less$/,
                 use: extractLESS.extract([ 'css-loader', 'less-loader' ])
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                loader: 'raw-loader',
                exclude: [/node_modules/]
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ fallback: 'style-loader', use: 'css-loader' }),
            },
            {
                test: /\.(ico)$/,
                loader: "url-loader?name=./[name].[ext]",
                include: path.resolve(__dirname, "content", "images")
            },
            {
                test: /\.svg$/,
                loader: 'svg-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|PNG|tiff|svg)$/,
                loader: 'file-loader?name=/[path]/[name].[ext]',
                include: path.resolve(__dirname, "content", "images"),
            },
            {
                test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
                loader: 'url-loader?minetype=application/font-woff&name=./fonts/[name].[ext]'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
                loader: 'file-loader?name=./fonts/[name].[ext]'
            },
            {
                test: require.resolve('adal-angular/lib/adal'),
                loader: 'expose-loader?AuthenticationContext'
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                enforce: "pre",
                loader: 'source-map-loader'
            }
        ],
    },

    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './app/layout.html',
            filename: 'index.html'
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({ name: 'vendor', filename: './scripts/vendor.bundle.js' }),
        new ExtractTextPlugin({ filename: './[name].bundle.css' }),
        /*
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(['./public'], {
            verbose: false
        }),
        */
        new AssetsPlugin({
            filename: 'webpack.assets.json',
            path: './public/scripts',
            prettyPrint: true
        }),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery',
            'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
            'window.$': 'jquery',
            "window.AuthenticationContext": "AuthenticationContext",
            _: 'underscore'
        }),

        new CopyWebpackPlugin([
            {from: './app/**/*.html', to: './'}
        ]),
        extractLESS // including the less files here
    ],
    externals: [
        { xmlhttprequest: '{XMLHttpRequest:XMLHttpRequest}' }
    ]

}
```

[image: public folder after build]

Here you can see that the less files have been compiled to css and included in the public(build) folder. Why do i get errors, if the config file executes as intended?

[image: sources from devtools]

Here it also shows that all the files are included in the application in the browser as well. I have checked all my dependencies and they are all running latest versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path for the imports in the less files, were incorrect. Here is the working references:

```
@import "~bootstrap/less/variables.less";
@import "~bootstrap/less/mixins/buttons.less";
@import "~font-awesome/less/font-awesome.less";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with your `font_awesome` path.

Try to change `import` to (`font_awesome` instead of `Font_awesome`)

```
 @import "node_modules/font-awesome/less/font-awesome.less";
```